# Install and run beanstalkd on Raspbian Bookworm with other processes

Tags: docker, dockerfile, beanstalkd

Complete Docker beginner here !

I'm trying to set up a Docker container based on Raspbian Bookworm which installs and runs Beanstalkd.  I then want to start a number of PHP processes which communicate with one another via Beanstalk queues.  I have this all working outside of Docker.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Define base image (Raspbian Bookworm)
FROM dtcooper/raspberrypi-os:latest

# Update
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y

# Install beanstalkd
RUN apt install -y beanstalkd

# Start Beanstalkd
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/beanstalkd -l 0.0.0.0 -p 11300

# Copy over files etc ...
COPY classes/ramdisk.php /myapp/classes/
COPY controller.php /myapp/

# Run controller
CMD ["php", "controller.php"]
```

Whilst beanstalkd installs it does not run when I run the container.  I've tried a variety of ways of solving this included the one shown above from here ([Beanstalkd in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328200/beanstalkd-in-docker)) and also by writing to /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d as described here ([How to solve "invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start." when building a container Ubuntu 14.04 and installing apache2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247032/how-to-solve-invoke-rc-d-policy-rc-d-denied-execution-of-start-when-building)) but neither solution works.  In both cases if I run the container and do:

```
ps ax | grep beanstalk
```

no process is running yet if I do:

```
service beanstalkd start
```

from the container command line then beanstalkd runs.

From my Dockerfile above you'll see that I want to start beanstalkd and then continue on to run other processes so, as I understand it, using ENTRYPOINT is probably not the best solution but CMD won't start beanstalkd either.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A container normally only runs one process.  You should not normally need the container command line at all.  For this setup, you probably need two separate containers.  They could use separate images, one with the code and one without, or the same image, overriding the `CMD` for one or the other.

Comment: Thanks - that seems extremely inefficient given that I'll need one container running beanstalkd and then three other containers running tiny (less than 5k) PHP scripts

Comment: A container itself isn't particularly expensive; it comes with a temporary copy-on-write filesystem and some kernel-level namespacing, but otherwise it just wraps its main process.  You're probably giving up much more time and memory using an interpreted language than splitting into separate containers would cost.

Comment: Fair enough - there is an additional overhead in terms of networking though.  One of my processes pulls data from a non-Dockerised localhost TCP port.  If I run multiple containers (beanstalk in one and my PHP processes in others) then I need to define a network to allow them to access the port and beanstalk.  By running beanstalk and my processes in the same container I was hoping to avoid all of that extra complication.